# Linear combinations vector

Tags: vector-spaces

im given 3 vectors - (1,-1), (3,0), (2,1) and I need to express a 4th one (1,1) as a linear combination of the others in 2 different ways..? Can someone please explain how I would do this?

Thanks

Comment: **Hint**: both $\left\{(1,-1),(3,0)\right\}$ and $\left\{(3,0),(2,1)\right\}$ are bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
t \begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1 \end{pmatrix}
+ u \begin{pmatrix} 3\\0 \end{pmatrix}
+ v \begin{pmatrix} 2\\1 \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Solving for $t,$ $u,$ and $v$
will give you a linear relationship among those three variables.
Choose two solutions of that linear relationship.

Or just pick a value of one of the three variables $t,$ $u,$ and $v,$
plug it into the equation above, and solve for the other two.
That gives you one linear combination.
Choose one of the variables, set it to a different value than it has
in the combination you already found, and solve for the other two
variables to get a different combination.

Answer (score 0):

Why/When is that possible in the first place?

If not caring, this can help:

If $v_1=(1,-1),v_2=(3,0),v_3=(2,1),v_4=(1,1)$:

$$x v_1 + y v_2 + z v_3=v_4 \implies$$
$$x + 3y + 2z = -x + z=1$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve for three scalars. You are given three vectors  $v_1$,  $v_2$, and $v_3$. You need to satisfy the equality
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix} = a v_1 + b v_2 + c v_3
\end{equation}